# Game of LIfe Hashing Python

Tags: python, hash, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to create a simple Game of Life by storing Cell objects into a set (have to use classes) and I reach the problem in which I cannot add the cell object into the Set because it is unhashable... is there any way around this? Thanks!

```
class Cell():
    def __init__(self, row, col):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
    def getRow(self):
        return self.row
    def getCol(self):
        return self.col
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
        else:
            return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)    

class SparseLifeGrid(set):
    # Creates a new infinite-sized game grid with all cells set to dead.
    def __init__(self):
        self.rowList = []
        self.colList = []
        self.cellSet = set()

    def __add__(self, cell):
        self.cellSet.add(cell)
        self.rowList.append(cell.getRow())     
        self.colList.append(cell.getCol())     

    def minRange(self):
        #Returns a 2-tuple (minrow, mincol) that contains the minimum
        #row index and the minimum
        #column index that is currently occupied by a live cell.
        #None is returned if there are no alive cells.        
        return (sorted(self.rowList)[0], sorted(self.rowList)[0])

    def maxRange(self):
        #Returns a 2-tuple (maxrow, maxcol) that contains the
        #maximum row index and the maximum
        #column index that is currently occupied by a live cell.
        #None is returned if there are no live cells.        
        return (sorted(self.rowList,reverse = True)[0],\
                sorted(self.colList,reverse = True)[0])

    def clearCell(self, row, col):
        #Clears the individual cell (row, col) and sets it to dead.
        #If the cell is already dead, no action is taken.
        for item in self:
            if item == Cell(row,col):
                self.remove(item)

    def setCell(self, row, col):
        #Sets the indicated cell (row, col) to be alive.
        #If the cell is already alive, no action is taken.
        self.__add__(Cell(row,col))

    def isLiveCell(self, row, col):
        #Returns a boolean value indicating if the given
        #cell (row, col) contains a live organism.
        return Cell(row,col) in self

    def numLiveNeighbors(self, row, col):
    #checks how many live adjacents (not diagonals I think) a cell has
        surround = 0
        if self.isLiveCell(row+1,col):
            surround += 1
        if self.isLiveCell(row-1,col):
            surround += 1
        if self.isLiveCell(row, col+1):
            surround += 1
        if self.isLiveCell(row, col-1):
            surround += 1
        return surround

G = SparseLifeGrid()
G.setCell(2,3)
```

Comment: [Why did you create getters?](http://archive.org/details/SeanKellyRecoveryfromAddiction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your Cell instances immutable, then create a `__hash__` method that always remains the same. If you can't use tuples directly, here's an alternative (that borrows only a little from `tuple`):

```
class Cell:
    # each cell will have exactly two values, so no need for __dict__
    __slots__ = ["row", "col"]

    # set up values at construction time using super().__setitem__()
    def __init__(self, row, col):
        super().__setitem__("row", row)
        super().__setitem__("col", col)
        return self

    # a Cell is intended to be immutable, so __setattr__ always raises an error
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if hasattr(self, name):
            raise AttributeError("{!r} object attribute {!r} is read-only"
                                 .format(self.__class__.__name__, name))
        else:
            raise AttributeError("{!r} object has no attribute {!r}"
                                 .format(self.__class__.__name__, name))

    # comparison operators
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (isinstance(other, Cell) and
                self.row == other.row and
                self.col == other.col)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

    # hash function, with a value borrowed from a tuple
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.row, self.col))
```

This is rather a lot of work though, for something that is equivalent to:

```
Cell = collections.namedtuple(["row", "col"])
```

Your grid class also has some issues. For instance, you're overriding `__add__`, which is used for implementing the addition operator, but you don't return anything, so it won't work like it would be expected to. I suspect you mean to be overriding the `add` method (with no underscores) instead. However, if that's the case, you'll want to be sure you call `super().add()` with appropriate arguments if you want your grid to actually function as a set.

Also, `min(lst)` should be much faster than `sorted(lst)[0]` (O(N) rather than O(N log N)).

Answer (score 0):

Your objects are mutable, and you haven't implemented `__hash__()`; but you don't really want to do that anyway.  Your cells are only there to indicate alive if they are present, so just use a tuple `(row, col)`  in your set.  Since tuples are immutable and hashable, you can put those in your set.

Use the classes and objects for the grid and the game, not the cells.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but I'm not allowed to use tuples in my set as the cells

Comment: I'd be sorely tempted to do `class Cell(tuple): pass`... ;) or perhaps a named tuple; but really, tuples are objects just as much as any others.